# SQL - Update table field using another table

Tags: mysql, sql, dql

I have two tables (**users** and **titles**) with this field's:

Users

- id
- name
- date
- title_id

Title

- id
- name
- position

I need update all ***titleId*** when users date was updated taking titles from users date in order descendant.

For example:

Title 1

- ID: 1
- Name: CEO
- Position: 1

Title 2

- ID: 2
- Name: CTO
- Position: 2

User 1

- Date: 2010-01-01
- TitleId: 1

User 2:

- Date: 2011-01-01
- TitleId: 2

Which is the best way to do it using MySQL or DQL?

Regards

**EDIT 1:**

First step:

I will update one date for one user:

```
UPDATE users SET date = NOW() WHERE id = 1;
```

After this a need update titleId for ALL users. So Im thinking for something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY date DESC
```

For each user I need take one title user position of the selection results. For example, first row will take first title position. Please remember titles table have and order field.

Comment: Give examples of date before and after update.

Comment: How would you know that on which date Id is updated better to keep a record for updation by triggers

Comment: I just edit my original question